# How to prevent error "more than 30 operands in 'asm'" with inline assesmbly with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have been writing a minimal lua compiler for educational purposes by translating the lua code to inline assembly in C with gcc.

After a while when my generated output started to become longer with more operands for declared variables and functions in C, this error started to occur.

```
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:100:6: error: more than 30 operands in ‘asm’
     );
```

When googling the only other info i found was [some gcc mailing list from 2008](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-03/msg00109.html), but they said that there were no fixes except for recompiling gcc (which I am not interested in).

The ironic thing is that often I don't even have 30 operands and I still get this error!

Here's an minimal example (with 19 operands, still gives me that error)

```
// Standard functions
void io_read(){}
void io_write(){}
void print(){}
int main(){
    // Working vars decl
    long _t0, _t1, _t2, _t3, _t4, _t5, _t6, _t7, _t8;
    long factorial, i, n, x;
    // Strings decl
    const char* _s0 = "enter a number:";
    const char* _s1 = "*number";
    const char* _s2 = "factorial of ";
    const char* _s3 = " is ";
    asm("" // My inline asm code
    : // Output symbols
      [_s0] "+g" (_s0),
      [_s1] "+g" (_s1),
      [_s2] "+g" (_s2),
      [_s3] "+g" (_s3),
      [_t0] "+g" (_t0),
      [_t1] "+g" (_t1),
      [_t3] "+g" (_t3),
      [_t4] "+g" (_t4),
      [_t5] "+g" (_t5),
      [_t6] "+g" (_t6),
      [_t7] "+g" (_t7),
      [_t8] "+g" (_t8),
      [factorial] "+g" (factorial),
      [i] "+g" (i),
      [n] "+g" (n),
      [x] "+g" (x)
    : // Input symbols
      [io_read] "r" (io_read),
      [io_write] "r" (io_write),
      [print] "r" (print)
    : // Clobbers
      "cc", "rax", "rbx", "rcx", "rdx"
    );
}
```

My gcc version is 6.2.1 20160830

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either reuse variables, or create tables (arrays) and use offsets into these arrays to get variables (inserted into the assembly code by your compiler).

Comment: Consider emitting proper assembly instead of inline assembly. gcc has a limit of 30 operands for inline assembly and it is not planned to remove that limit.

Comment: Wouldn't generating C code be much easier and simpler to debug? And why don't you directly generate an Assmbler file? No offence, but that intermediate C stage looks much like nonsense to me.

Comment: @Olaf I would love to just write plain assembler because I don't see the use for the inline assembler honestly, but sadly it's a university assignment and to get a B I have to do it with a single inline asm statement.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the suggestion, didn't think of that. While its just a workaround rather than a solution I'll do that if i don't come up with anything else.

Comment: @JohanBjäreholt: Another nonsense constraint far from reality. Recommendation: switch course or university. You can cite me: Your tutor seems to have no idea about compilers. (I'd understand compiling to C, though)

Comment: I believe your input/output `"+g"` operands count as two operands. You should be able to make the `_s#` operands input-only operands and the rest output-only early-clobber `"&g"` operands. You can refer to `io_read`. `io_write` and `print` directly in your assembly without using `asm` operands, though you'll have to find out whether your platform expects `_print` or `print`.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks alot, that is incredibly useful. Didn't know that +g counted as two operands. With these optimizations i should hopefully be able to most things i had planned to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I didn't find a direct solution to the issue, but thanks to [Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826372/ross-ridge) I was able to work around the issue pretty well.

The first imrovement i did was changing "+g" with "g" where possible. Apparently "+g" counts as two operands because it allows both read+write so I replaced the onces possible with "g" which only allows write.

Also, I was able to completely remove my functions as operands by moving them to a global scope and then calling then directly with "call print" instead of "call %[print]". It should be noted however that this only work with inline C and will not work with inline C++.

If you are writing a compiler like me I would recommend staying away from inline assembly though. Seems like more trouble, simply calling C functions manually from Assembler would be easier, and I would certainly not make a compiler on a bigger scale with inline C.

EDIT: I started forcing "m" and "+m" also instead of using "g" and force variables onto the stack which seems to work fine.

Comment: `"=g"` is write only.  `"g"` is read-only.  IDK why you want to output inline-asm at all.  That seems like a horrible idea.  Just output pure C, or pure asm (into a `.s` which defines `main`).  Making function calls from inside inline asm isn't even safe, because you can't tell gcc that you want to clobber the red-zone.  Taking function-pointers as inputs to your inline-asm is really horrible, since you get a register or memory-indirect call through an actual function pointer.

Comment: You're still leaving out any mention of `"=m"` or `"=g"`, which is what you should be using when the output is write-only.  I'd recommend using as many +/=/`g` operands as gcc will allow, and +/=/`m` for the rest, since forcing everything to the stack will make garbage asm.  (Although if you already clobber all the registers and do register allocation yourself, which I guess you'd have to since you need to avoid producing `addl mem, mem` or whatever, everything will be on the stack anyway, except immediate constants.  So you should still use `g` for inputs, to allow immediates.)